# Does awk CR LF handling break on cygwin?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

On Linux, this runs as expected:

```
$ echo -e "line1\r\nline2"|awk -v RS="\r\n" '/^line/ {print "awk: "$0}'
awk: line1
awk: line2
```

But under windows the \r is dropped (awk considers this one line):

Windows:

```
$ echo -e "line1\r\nline2"|awk -v RS="\r\n" '/^line/ {print "awk: "$0}'
awk: line1
line2
```

Windows GNU Awk 4.0.1
Linux GNU Awk 3.1.8

EDIT from @EdMorton (sorry if this is an unwanted addition but I think maybe it helps demonstrate the issue):

Consider this RS setting and input (on cygwin):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{printf "\"%s\"\n", RS}' | cat -v
"
"
$ echo -e "line1\r\nline2" | cat -v
line1^M
line2
```

This is Solaris with gawk:

```
$ echo -e "line1\r\nline2" | awk '1' | cat -v   
line1^M
line2
```

and this is cygwin with gawk:

```
$ echo -e "line1\r\nline2" | awk '1' | cat -v
line1
line2
```

`RS` was just it's default newline so where did the control-M go in cygwin?

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that in cygwin too. I couldn't be bothered to investigate or debug it and I have very few files that have `\r`s in them so when necessary I just stuck a `tr -d '\r' | awk ...` in front of it to delete the `\r`s. Hopefully someone will shed some light though - good question!

Comment: Have you tried `-v IRS` ? Note I for input

Comment: `awk -v IRS=something`? That would set an unused, user-defined awk variable named `IRS` to `something`. It would have no impact to this issue.

Comment: @EdMorton Indeed, I did not test it. I just assumed like with FS.

Comment: It is like `FS`. There is neither an `IFS` nor an `IRS` variable, there's `FS`, `RS`, `OFS`, and `ORS`.

Comment: echo -e "line1\r\nline2"|awk -v RS="\n" '/^line/ {print "awk: "$0}' -- works in both

Comment: The issue seems to be that `awk` won't ever match `\r` as a record separator, let alone `\r\n`.  I tried different notations such as `\015` and `\x0d` and it still never matches.  I also ruled out `echo` being a culprit by using a file as an input instead of piping from `echo`.  It genuinely seems like `awk` is incapable of matching `\r`.

Comment: @arun, what version `awk -V`?

Comment: GNU Awk 4.1.0, API: 1.0 (GNU MPFR 3.1.2, GNU MP 4.3.2) in Cygwin. awk --version in Linux server: GNU Awk 3.1.5

Comment: `echo $'\r'|awk 1|od -a|egrep cr` If this outputs nothing, awk has the bug.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just checked with Arnold Robbins (the provider of gawk) and the answer is that it's something done by the C libraries and to stop it happening you should set the awk BINMODE variable to 3:

```
$ echo -e "line1\r\nline2" | awk '1' | cat -v
line1
line2

$ echo -e "line1\r\nline2" | awk -v BINMODE=3 '1' | cat -v
line1^M
line2
```

See the man page for more info if interested.

Comment: Using BINMODE works on Linux too although I don't want to assume this is the reason for all of this.  Maybe Arnold can suggest a fix (making this a default for windows perhaps).

Comment: I think this is an issue for more than gawk, and having gawk work around it would probably break existing scripts and/or introduce conflicts with other functionality/tools, etc. so I wouldn't even ask Arnold to look at this one. I'm just happy to have something that works!

Answer (score 4):

It seems like the issue is `awk` specific under Cygwin.
I tried a few different things and it seems that `awk` is silently treating replacing `\r\n` with `\n` in the input data.

If we simply ask `awk` to repeat the text unmodified, it will "sanitize" the carriage returns without asking:

```
$ echo -e "line1\r\nline2" | od -a
0000000   l   i   n   e   1  cr  nl   l   i   n   e   2  nl
0000015

$ echo -e "line1\r\nline2" | awk '{ print $0; }' | od -a
0000000   l   i   n   e   1  nl   l   i   n   e   2  nl
0000014
```

It will, however, leave other carriage returns intact:

```
$ echo -e "Test\rTesting\r\nTester\rTested" | awk '{ print $0; }' | od -a
0000000   T   e   s   t  cr   T   e   s   t   i   n   g  nl   T   e   s
0000020   t   e   r  cr   T   e   s   t   e   d  nl
0000033
```

Using a custom record separator of `_` ended up leaving the carriage returns intact:

```
$ echo -e "Testing\r_Tested" | awk -v RS="_" '{ print $0; }' | od -a
0000000   T   e   s   t   i   n   g  cr  nl   T   e   s   t   e   d  nl
0000020  nl
0000021
```

The most telling example involves having `\r\n` in the data, but not as a record separator:

```
$ echo -e "Testing\r\nTested_Hello_World" | awk -v RS="_" '{ print $0; }' | od -a
0000000   T   e   s   t   i   n   g  nl   T   e   s   t   e   d  nl   H
0000020   e   l   l   o  nl   W   o   r   l   d  nl  nl
0000034
```

`awk` is blindly converting `\r\n` to `\n` in the input data even though we didn't ask it to.

This substitution seems to be happening before applying record separation, which explains why `RS="\r\n"` never matches anything.  By the time `awk` is looking for `\r\n`, it's already substituted it with `\n` in the input data.

Comment: +1; great sleuthing. [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS) exhibits the same behavior. `sed` also exhibits this behavior on at least MSYS presumably also on Cygwin; try `sed '' <<<$'line1\r\nline2' | od -a`.

Comment: Isn't this what we started with and were looking for "why" and "how do we stop it from doing that"???