# Different awk results on Linux and mingw64 with CRLF line endings

Tags: awk, mingw, mingw-w64

On Linux:

```
echo -n $'boo\r\nboo\r\n' | awk $'BEGIN { RS="\\n" } {gsub("boo","foo"); print}' | cat -v
```

returns the expected

```
foo^M
foo^M
```

However, on mingw64 (git bash for windows) the same command returns:

```
foo
foo
```

without the carriage returns.

I tried setting the record separator explicitly since maybe the default was different between the two platforms, but awk on mingw64 is still chewing up the carriage returns. How can I made awk do the same thing on Linux on mingw64? Note the awk versions are slightly different (GNU Awk 4.0.2 on Linux and GNU Awk 4.2.1 on mingw64), but I wouldn't expect this to matter unless there is some kind of bug.

Note that something is happening specifically in awk since on mingw64 this:

```
echo -n $'boo\r\nboo\r\n' | cat -v
```

returns the expected:

```
boo^M
boo^M
```

Comment: `GNU awk 4.1.4` from `cygwin`, the same. Thanks for bring this up.

Comment: Presumably it's smart enough to convert Windows style line endings on Windows when reading the input data.

Comment: Found the solution, check my answer below. And I suggest you to check the question & answer I linked to, and upvote them :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching a while, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24251296/5403468), And from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24377916/5403468) :

> it's something done by the C libraries and to stop it happening you should set the awk BINMODE variable to 3

I changed your code to:

```
echo -n $'boo\r\nboo\r\n' | awk -v BINMODE=3 $'BEGIN { RS="\\n" } {gsub("boo","foo"); print}' | cat -v
```

And tried it on Unix, Linux, MacOS, and Windows, all produce this output:

```
foo^M
foo^M
```

So `-v BINMODE=3` is what you are looking for.
**NOTE** that only `-v BINMODE=3` this switch & before code way working.
Usually we can pass variable to awk by `-v` switch, in `BEGIN` block, or set it after code before files,
but in this case I tried the three ways, only `-v BINMODE=3` works.
Guess it's something to do with `awk`'s compiling process.

Example (under `cygwin` on Windows):

```
$ echo -n $'boo\r\nboo\r\n' | awk -v BINMODE=3 '1' | cat -v    
boo^M                                                          
boo^M                                                          

$ echo -n $'boo\r\nboo\r\n' | awk 'BEGIN{BINMODE=3}1' | cat -v 
boo                                                            
boo                                                            

$ echo -n $'boo\r\nboo\r\n' | awk '1' BINMODE=3 | cat -v       
boo                                                            
boo
```

Under other mentioned platforms, they all produce:

```
boo^M
boo^M
```